# The select drop down's click event gets delayed when its appears on a Modal Pop-up

Tags: jquery

We have a select drop down which comes up on a modal popup. The click event of the select has time lag. The select contains hundreds of options. The select works pretty fast when it is placed on the main page.

Can anyone tell me how to improve the select drop down's performance on the modal pop-up?

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: can you maybe show a demo?